# how to use cleveref with IEEEeqnarray?

Tags: cross-referencing, ieeetran, cleveref

Here is the codes. I have 3 questions about the labeling by using the packages `IEEEtrantools` and `cleveref` together.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefname{ineq}{Ineq.}{Ineqs.}
\Crefname{ineq}{Inequality}{Inequalities}
\creflabelformat{ineq}{~\upshape(#2#1#3)}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\section{IEEE}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl} 
a
&>&b+c \IEEEyessubnumber\label[ineq]{1a}\\ 
&>&f+g \IEEEyessubnumber\label[ineq]{2a}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

I have 2 questions here.
1) In PDF, the labels behind the inequalities are (1.0a) and (1.0b). 
How can I get (1.1a) and (1.1b)?
2) The command \verb|\cref| gives \cref{1b,2b}.
How can I get ``Ineqs. (1.1a) and (1.1b)'' by using \verb|\cref|?

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl} 
a
&<&b+c \IEEEyessubnumber\label[ineq]{1b}\\ 
&<&f+g \IEEEyessubnumber\label[ineq]{2b}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

I have another question here.
3) In PDF, the labels behind the inequalities are (1.0c) and (1.0d). 
How can I get (1.2a) and (1.2b)?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I can address questions 1 and 3 fully. I'm afraid I can offer only work-arounds for question 2.

Regarding question 3: Use `\IEEEyesnumber` before `\IEEEyessubnumber` in the inequality labelled `1b`.

Regarding question 1: Since you're using the `amsart` document class, which loads the `amsmath` package, it turns out to be better *not* to use the `\IEEEyessubnumber` directives and, instead, to encase the `IEEEeqnarray` environments in `subequation` environments. With this change in place, the printed equation "numbers" come out as expected. (If you make this change, you should omit all `\IEEEyesnumber` and `\IEEEyessubnumber` directives.)

Regarding question 2: With `subequation` environments in use, the *names* of the items being cross-referenced via `\cref` -- `Ineqs` -- are correct but the *numbers* are not: `\cref{1b,2b}` produces "Ineqs. (1.2) and (1.2)" rather than "Ineqs. (1.1a) and (1.1b)". (If the `[ineq]` qualifiers are omitted, the name changes from "Ineqs." to "Eqs." but the numbers are still incorrect; hence, the problem isn't caused by the use of the `[ineq]` label modifiers.) I can only surmise that `cleveref`'s support for the `IEEEeqnarray` environment isn't perfect. Contacting the authors of the `cleveref` and `IEEEtrantools` packages and asking them for a fix is probably the way to go to get a complete solution.

In the meantime, it's possible to work around this problem by writing

```
... Ineqs.~\eqref{1a}) and~\eqref{1b} ...
```

This foresakes the elegance of `\cref`, but it has the merit of working.

A separate potential work-around: The `\cref` macro is known to work very well with the `amsmath`-based multiline-math environments. Thus, you may want to consider switching from the environments of the `IEEEtrantools` package to those of the `amsmath` package. (Note that the `amsmath` package is loaded automatically by the `amsart` document class.) As an intermediate step, you could choose to use the `amsmath` environments just for those equation groups that involve subequation-style numbering.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefname{ineq}{Ineq.}{Ineqs.}
\Crefname{ineq}{Inequality}{Inequalities}
\creflabelformat{ineq}{~\upshape(#2#1#3)}

\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\section{IEEE}

\subsection{Using \texttt{subequations} and \texttt{IEEEeqnarray}}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl} 
a &>&b+c \label[ineq]{1a}\\ 
  &>&f+g \label[ineq]{2a}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{subequations}

The printed ``numbers'' are (1.1a) and (1.1b), as desired.

\verb|\cref| gives ``\cref{1a,2a}'', but ``Ineqs. (1.1a) and (1.1b)'' is desired.


\subsection{Using \texttt{subequations} and \texttt{align}}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} 
a &<b+c \label[ineq]{1b}\\ 
  &<f+g \label[ineq]{2b}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

The printed ``numbers'' are (1.2a) and (1.2b), as desired.

\verb|\cref{1b,2b}| gives ``\cref{1b,2b}'', also as desired.

\end{document}
```